# Intelligence, Internet usage and Ip addresses

Tags: data-request, internet

I was looking for information about -

1. If intelligence predicts internet usage.
2. A relation between IP addresses per capita versus GDP per capita.

I'd greatly appreciate any sources or just raw data on any one or both of these.

**Notes:**

Google search did not yield much but maybe i'm not doing it right.

I tried I found some things on wolfram alpha though.

I did find a relationships indicating that in developing countries, there were more IP addresses per person compared to other undeveloped countries.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: MaxMind.com provides free (coarse) database showing the distribution of IP addresses to countries/cities: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/

Comment: Please be careful with statements like "If intelligence predicts internet usage." IP addresses and internet usage are correlated to GDP per capita, as you show. But I would be very skeptical about making an assumption about the "intelligence" of a person who has no access to education, health care, technology, and a stable government.

Comment: @Philshem Why should I be 'careful'? Additionally, can you prove your skepticism?

Comment: @user67707 Please define intelligence in a global way. And as a skeptic, it's not my job to prove anything - it's up to you to reverse my skepticism.

Comment: @philshem is quite right: what do you mean by intelligence? Can be education, IQ, creative output etc. Moreover, you'll show a correlation. You have to be careful – I cannot emphasise this enough – because people will interpret it as "if you're smart, you're more likely to use the internet" which is completely unfounded given the above.

Answer (score 1):

Going by country is pretty coarse. But as indicated in my earlier comment, I would start with the (coarse) database showing the distribution of IP addresses to countries/cities: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite.

I would then use the World Bank datasets on economic related data per country, such as:

- GDP
- Economic Indicators
- Gender Statistics
- Education Statistics
- GNI Gross National Income per capita
- Health and Nutrition Indicators

http://datacatalog.worldbank.org/